# Have trouble with "Expression is not assignable"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

I have trouble with the code below:
The "rectView" is a UIView, and its bounds's origin should be a CGPoint, so why it does not work?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
`rectView.bounds.origin = CGPointMake(50, 100);
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply assign an origin to a view, but you can assign a new bounds/frame using that origin value doing something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
     CGRect originalRect = rectView.bounds;
     rectView.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 10, originalRect.size.width, originalRect.size.height);
}];
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to use `__block` with `originalRect since you are not assigning a value to the variable inside the block. 2) There is no reason to have `originalRect` created outside the block at all`.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. I'll edit, thanks!

Comment: BTW why I should put the CGRect originalRect = rectView.bounds outside?

Comment: You don't need to - see edit.